# elegant way to check and delete element from list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am searching for an elegant way to iterate over an ArrayList to check each entry and delete them if the check fails. Now it looks like this:

```
ArrayList<String> a, b;
int counter = 0;

a = readSometingIntoList();
b = (ArrayList<String>) a.clone();

for (String s : a) {
   if(checkFails(s)) {
      b.remove( b.indexOf(s) + counter);
      counter++;
      }
   }
}

a = (ArrayList<String>) b.clone();
```

Is there a trick to do it shorter or more elegant?

Comment: create a new list, each iteration, if valid, add the element to the new list, after the last iteration, overwrite the old list with the new one

Comment: What is your checkFails(), it doesn't take any parameter? So it seems to independent from iteration over list you do.

Comment: Try something like that: List<String> result = a.stream().filter(a -> checkFails()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @Stultuske I'll try that. thank you.